# Extendscript for Adobe Illustrator: Unexpected compound shape / path results from expanding image trace

Tags: javascript, vector, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am writing a script in Extendscript for adobe illustrator that would automate these steps for an ink like effect: 1)Expand the selected object 2)convert to a compound shape 3)apply gaussian blur 4)rasterize 5)image trace. Here is how this looks when done manually:

Before doing the steps manually:

[image: Before doing the steps manually]

after doing the steps manually:

[image: after doing the steps manually]

You can see a slight rounding effect to the edges. That is how i intend this.

However, when running these steps from my script, i get this result:

after result from script:

[image: after result from script]

The rounded effect applied as was expected, but the empty spaces in paths always turn out filled. As if the script was releasing the compound path.

I am wondering where in the script this could be happening, and how to prevent that ?

Here is the code for the function where the effect is being applied:

```
    function mainFunction(){
        inkifyScript.selection = app.activeDocument.selection;
        
        if (inkifyScript.selection.length > 0){
    
            app.executeMenuCommand('group');
            inkifyScript.xmlString = '<LiveEffect name="Adobe PSL Gaussian Blur"><Dict data="R blur '+ 20 +'"/></LiveEffect>';
            for (var i = 0; i < inkifyScript.selection.length; i++){
                inkifyScript.selection[i].applyEffect(inkifyScript.xmlString);
            }
            
            inkifyScript.raster = app.activeDocument.rasterize(selection[0]);
            inkifyScript.raster.selected = true;

            inkifyScript.pluginItem = inkifyScript.raster.trace();

            inkifyScript.tracingOptions = inkifyScript.pluginItem.tracing.tracingOptions;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.tracingMode = TracingModeType.TRACINGMODEBLACKANDWHITE;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.ignoreWhite = true;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.fills = true;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.maxColors = 2;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.threshold = 142;
            inkifyScript.tracingOptions.pathFitting = 10;
            app.redraw();
            inkifyScript.pluginItem.tracing.expandTracing();    
        }
        
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer !

Adding the following line resolved the issue, in order to make ignoreWhite work properly:

```
tracingOptions.tracingMethod = TracingMethodType.TRACINGMETHODABUTTING;
```

Source: answer from another thread
[Link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/extendscript-unexpected-compound-shape-path-results-from-expanding-image-trace/m-p/13810881#M368062)

Comment: Ok. But it should be `inkifyScript.tracingOptions.tracingMethod = ...` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
inkifyScript.tracingOptions.ignoreWhite = true;
```

to:

```
inkifyScript.tracingOptions.ignoreWhite = false;
```

It adds white areas, though. So probably it's a partial solution. To get a real filled compound paths it will need to remove the white background, and apply the command Object > Compound Path > Make:

[image]

I believe, these final steps can be performed with a couple lines of a script as well. Probably this addition will do the trick:

Change this line:

```
inkifyScript.pluginItem.tracing.expandTracing();
```

With this:

```
var result = inkifyScript.pluginItem.tracing.expandTracing(); // get the result
result.selected = true;                                       // select the result
result.pathItems[result.pathItems.length-1].remove();         // remove the white background
app.executeMenuCommand('compoundPath');                       // make a compound path
```